# Installing Allegro

Tags: cmake, allegro

I have been following [this](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Install_Allegro5_From_Git/Windows#Optional_Dependencies%22this%22) procedure to install Allegro.Everything was ok until I reached point 3, where I have to run these commands

`cd C:\devel\a5_sourcepack\zlib
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\MinGW -G "MinGW Makefiles"
mingw32-make install`

1. the "build" directory already exists, I don't know why it makes me create it.
2. I tried to use the already existing build directory and run the following command but it gives me

   `C:\devel\a5_sourcepack\zlib\build>cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\MinGW -G "MinGW Makefiles"
   CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory C:/devel/a5_sourcepack/zlib/build/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory c:/dev/a5_sourcepack/zlib/build where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
   CMake Error: The source "C:/devel/a5_sourcepack/zlib/CMakeLists.txt" does not match the source "C:/dev/a5_sourcepack/zlib/CMakeLists.txt" used to generate cache.  Re-run cmake with a different source directory.`

I have even tried to run the last command `mingw32-make install` but it tells me there is no such command.

Comment: Any commands to mingw won't work outside of the installation folder unless it is added to your environment variables. Is mingw added as a system variable?

Answer (score -1):

Delete build directory and recreate it (with `mkdir`). Alternatively, remove all files from the build directory.

Then execute `cmake` command with needed arguments.

---

The error messages are self-explanatory: it seems you firstly have sources under `C:/dev/a5_sourcepack/zlib` and tried to build them in the `build/` subdirectory. Then you move sources into `C:/devel/a5_sourcepack/zlib` (probably, by renaming `dev` directory to `devel`).

But once CMake build files has been created (on running `cmake ...`), neither source nor build directory should be moved. Otherwise build files becomes invalid.